# Spyder 4: changed behavior or "run cell" / run selected code

Tags: python, spyder

I'm a user of spyder. This weekend I updated to spyder 4, which seems to have received many usefull improvements, however I have a problem with running selected code. The logic seems to have changed.

Unfortunately for me it is very important, that I can select code lines and run them ad hoc, without copying them to the shell each time. For older versions of spyder this could be easily done by selecting the code and pressing [Ctrl]+[Enter], but now this seems to execute not just the code I selected. To be honest, I don't even know, what it executes.

The same applies if I select "run cell" from the menu after selecting code.

Can anybody shed some light into this? how can I execute selected code in spyder 4?

For me this functionality is so important, that I really think about downgrading to a lower version, even though I would lose big improvements in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ctrl]+[Enter] is for debugging mode and F9 is what you are looking for.

See also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031796/how-to-run-current-line-in-spyder-3-5-ctrl-f10-not-working).

Comment: Thank's I didn't see this. But the logic of execute cell must have been changed (this worked the same way if code was selected in the old version).